# Parallelizing bitmap methods

Tags: c#, image, task-parallel-library

I created a class called QuickBitmap to quickly get/set pixels in a `Bitmap` object. Using intertops I'm able to safely lock/unlock the bits of the `Bitmap` and with the use of methods like `SaveBits`, `LoadBits`, `UpdateUnderlayingBitmap`, `GetPixel` and `SetPixel`. I can quickly and easily manipulate the image.

The problem:

One of my methods changes the bitdepth to 32 bits. If I use it I'm no longer able to quickly determine if the image I'm manipulating was, originally, composed of only black and white colors.

I created the following methods do it:

```
private IEnumerable<Color> AllPixels()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Width;i++ )
    {
        for(int j=0; j<Height; j++)
        {
            yield return GetPixel(i, j);
        }
    }
}

public bool IsBlackAndWhiteParallel()
{
    return AllPixels().AsParallel().All(x => x.IsBlackOrWhite());
}
```

But as you can guess, it's quite a slow method. So I googled a little and found out that I can break a parallel.for loop.
So I rewrote my method do this:

```
public bool IsBlackAndWhiteParallel()
{
    bool ret = true;
    Parallel.For(0, Width, (i, loopstate) =>
    {
        for(int j=0; j<Height; j++)
        {
            if(!GetPixel(i,j).IsBlackOrWhite())
            {
                ret = false;
                loopstate.Stop();
            }
        }
    });

    return ret;
}
```

I benchmarked the code using the benchmark class (I found it in an old question on SO) with 100 iterations:

> ```
> public static class Benchmarker
> {
>     public static void Profile(string description, int iterations, Action func)
>     {
>         // warm up 
>         func();
>
>         Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
>
>         // clean up
>         GC.Collect();
>         GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
>         GC.Collect();
>
>         watch.Start();
>         for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
>         {
>             func();
>         }
>         watch.Stop();
>         Console.Write(description);
>         Console.WriteLine(" average time: {0} ms", watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds/iterations);
>     }
> }
> ```

Results:

- First code: 1170 ms
- Second code: 99 ms

This is how the getpixe/setpixel methods are implemented for 32 bits image:

```
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public Color GetPixel(int x, int y)
    {
        int pos;
        int r, g, b, a;

        pos = (y * stride) + (x * 4);

        b = bytes[pos];
        g = bytes[pos + 1];
        r = bytes[pos + 2];
        a = bytes[pos + 3];

        return Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public void SetPixel(int x, int y, Color c)
    {
        int pos;

        pos = (y * stride) + (x * 4);

        bytes[pos] = c.B;
        bytes[pos + 1] = c.G;
        bytes[pos + 2] = c.R;
        bytes[pos + 3] = c.A;
    }
```

I'm satisfied with the result, but I'd like to know if you have any suggestions for improvements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using [BitConverter.ToInt32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can simplify the `GetPixel()` method to

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
public Color GetPixel(int x, int y)
{
    return Color.FromArgb(BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, y * stride + x * 4));
}
```

Also there is no need to place `()` arround the multiplications because they will be done first.

---

Because `GetPixel` and `SetPixel` are public you should add some validation to them. This can be done by adding a private method `GetPosition()` like

```
private int GetPosition(int x, int y)
{
    if (x > stride) { throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("x"); }

    int position = y * stride + x * 4;

    if (position >= bytes.Length) { throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("y"); }
    return position;
}
```

now the changed `GetPixel()` method looks like

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
public Color GetPixel(int x, int y)
{
    return Color.FromArgb(BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, GetPosition(x, y)));
}
```

---

Basically you don't need the `Color` to determine if a pixel is black or white. You can just check if the argb value of that pixel matches the values for `Color.Black` or `Color.White` like

```
private const int black = -16777216;
private const int white = -1;

public bool IsBlackAndWhite(int x, int y)
{
    int argb = BitConverter.ToInt32(GetPosition(x, y));
    return argb == white || argb == black;
}
```

---

You should let your variables some space to breathe.

> ```
> for(int j=0; j<Height; j++)
> ```

should be

```
for(int j = 0; j < Height; j++)
```

Your IDE will usually have a keyboard shortcut for formatting the code.

---

Declaring multiple variables in one line makes your code less readable.

Answer (score 2):

**Var**

Use the `var` keyword when defining local variables where the right hand side of the definition makes the type obvious. This looks cleaner and saves time when it comes to changing types during refactoring.

e.g.

```
bool ret = true;
```

should be

```
var ret = true;
```

You should also use `var` when defining loop variables.

e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
```

should be

```
for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
```

**Naming**

Avoid using shortened names. The extra characters don't cost anything and can be immensely helpful for a maintenance programmer (or yourself in a few months).

e.g.

```
bool ret = true;
```

would be better off named something like `result`. The same goes for `r`,`g`,`b` and `a`, although you would be forgiven for leaving them contracted, since they are commonly-used names.

**Design**

You don't have to declare your variables up at the top. In fact, it's often clearer if you declare your variables as close to where you use them as possible.

e.g.

```
int pos;
int r, g, b, a;

pos = (y * stride) + (x * 4);

b = bytes[pos];
g = bytes[pos + 1];
r = bytes[pos + 2];
a = bytes[pos + 3];
```

should be

```
int pos = (y * stride) + (x * 4);

int b = bytes[pos];
int g = bytes[pos + 1];
int r = bytes[pos + 2];
int a = bytes[pos + 3];
```

Additionally, I question your use of `int` here, when bytes should clearly be containing `byte`. Why the cast when storing it in a variable?

Comment: I use int because the Color.FromArb build method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at1k42eh(v=vs.110).aspx takes ints as parameters.

Comment: Also. Thanks for all the suggestions! I'm kinda new to C# and not used to the var keyword. I'll also try to use more intuitive names for my variables.

Comment: There is an implicit conversion from `byte` to `int`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx meaning you don't need to explicitly cast. This means your variables can be bytes (which better represents their stored data) and you can still pass them in to `Color.FromArgb`

Comment: For somebody new to C# I am impressed. I've seen significantly worse code from seasoned veterans

Comment: That's news for me. Didn't know there was such conversion.

Comment: For what it’s worth, I don’t support the lazy typing using var. As someone who reads other people’s code a lot (and often has to modify or make changes), having everything declared as var in code is a pain - hovering over each variable to see what it’s actually cast as. This is especially true when dealing with custom class and such. The arguments for it don’t seem to mitigate the lack of readability for code.

Comment: Under the conditions I recommend var is used (i.e. when RHS of assignment makes the type obvious) and in appropriately small methods (as ideally methods are), I don't believe readability to be an issue when using var, as typically the assignment line makes the type obvious and is only a few lines away from its use.